# marijuana testing process

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

Does anyone know a bit about how costly and accurate are the current THC measurement techniques?

Please speculate what drives cost chemicals, consumables or instrument time.

Comment: This is a rather broad but interesting question, there are several different general methods for the anaylsis of drugs of abuse. You need to consider what are you trying to do in the lab. I would consider the testing of urine samples and the assay of lumps of resin / plant matter to be different problems.

Comment: I would imagine that LC-MS would produce a good analysis and the current generation of machines are fairly expensive, tens of thousands of dollars

Comment: In many states in the US, THC and CBD are recognized as medicinal, and there is a great need to certify these substances for purity and composition.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, THC testing is advertised online for the following prices:

--[Green Leaf Lab](https://greenleaflab.org/pricing/): $75

--[Pharm Labs](https://greenleaflab.org/pricing/) : $75

These companies both use HPLC. Without looking anything up, I'd guess that: The machine is around $100,000. It measures a sample every 30 minutes. (There might be modern marvels of engineering that run several samples in parallel and run way faster - idk.) Solvents and consumables are cheap. Maintaining the HPLC is expensive. You need a trained technician to prepare samples, run the analysis, and troubleshoot. That's expensive. You also need someone to deal with customers, which can be time-consuming as well.

You are not the only person thinking about THC testing. Google finds a handful of articles on what a business opportunity it is, and [equipment manufacturers are ready to sell you stuff](https://www.agilent.com/en/promotions/cannabis).

Good luck!